# Is there a way to do a search on my favorite questions ?

Tags: support, feature-request, profile-page, bookmarks, search

My list of favorited questions is getting longer, and it would be nice to be able to do a search on favorites. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be useful, but only for those that have many favorites, and that is probably a small number of users. This means that it is lower on the priority list.

It used to exist, but in the beginning of 2011 [search was moved from SQL Server to Lucene](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/). Lucene is not a classic SQL database, and not optimized for these kind of operations (joins against another table).

This [has also been asked on other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78946/reimplement-the-broken-searching-within-favorites-functionality) in the Stack Exchange network, once it gets implemented, all sites will get it.

Comment: Thanks Jan, the best would actually be a search that allows to find questions / answers / favorites on a user profile. I guess a quick fix would be a "show all" next to the pagination so we can do a browser search, like suggested in the thread you link to. I wonder if a [user script](http://userscripts.org/tags/stackoverflow) would not be able to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be an option according to [advanced search operators](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search).

Comment: Yes, I had seen the search options and wondered if anybody had a trick to do that. Wouldn't it be a useful feature ?